# Difference between Get-Member vs -Properties *

Tags: powershell

I am wondering what the differences are between `Get-Member` vs `-Properties *` in PowerShell.

I do `Get-ADUser AAA | Get-Member` and  `Get-ADUser AAA -Properties *`.

Why does `-Properties *` give me way more results than `Get-Member`.

What is the difference? I thought `Get-Member` is for listing all properties of a object which is the same as `-Properties *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-properties` is to specify additional properties that are not part of the default set of user object properties: [MS Get-ADuser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps).

`Get-Member` just gets the properties and methods of objects [MS Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6)

When you are piping your `Get-ADUser` into `Get-Member` it is just getting the default properties of the user object. If you specify additional/all properties using `-properties *` it will return all the AD user's properties (assuming you have rights).

Example:

- Default Properties:

  `Get-ADuser AAA | Get-Member`
- All AD User Properties:

  `Get-ADUser AAA -Properties * | Get-Member`